# Why are bent arrows with arrow tips not symmetric in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

They say a picture says more than a thousand words.
[image]

Is there a good reason why TikZ draws the arrows as skewed as in the left image? Is there any easy way to get good-looking, symmetric arrows as in the right picture without manually positioning the arrow tips?

**Note:** The line overlaps the fine tip of the arrows in the right image. This is not intentional, but adding `shorten >=2pt` also messes with the bend of the line.

Here's the code that produces the image above (without the captions).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \node[draw,circle] at (0,0) (A) {A};
    \node[draw,circle] at (1,0) (B) {B};
    \draw[->] (A) to[out=45, in=135] (B);
    \draw[->] (B) to[out=-135, in=-45] (A);
    \draw[help lines] (0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \node[draw,circle] at (0,0) (A) {A};
    \node[draw,circle] at (1,0) (B) {B};

    \draw (A) to[out=45, in=135] (B);    % Draw nice line
    \draw[<-] (B.135) -- ++(-0.1,0.066); % Add arrow tip

    \draw (A) to[out=-45, in=-135] (B);  % Draw nice line
    \draw[<-] (A.-45) -- ++(0.1,-0.066); % Add arrow tip

    \draw[help lines] (0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your comment about shorten is spot on.  When pgf draws an arrow, it shortens the line.  But it shortens it by displacing the end-point not by shortening the actual line as the latter is computationally more difficult.  I think we've had a similar question, but not sure how similar.

Comment: A question: Why do you add the arrow tip separately?

Comment: Not an answer, but have you considered using XY-pic? Its syntax for drawing small diagrams like the ones in your examples is much more concise than TikZ's, and I *think* its curved arrows are symmetric (although I haven't looked closely).

Comment: @Alenanno I added it separately because adding it the normal way screws up the lines (as seen in the left example). It's just a hack to show how it *should* look approximately.

Comment: @sampablokuper Since I already include TikZ in virtually all my documents, the XY syntax looks a bit arcane (at first glance) and learning a new language (that can do less than TikZ) doesn't sound *that* appealing... No, I haven't considered it `;-)`. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

The choice `latex` is a bad idea because it's not possible to get a correct result. The size of the arrow is to big . Look at the result of your "fine" attempt

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=to]
  \node[draw,circle] at (0,0) (A) {A};
  \node[draw,circle] at (1,0) (B) {B};
  \draw[->] (A) to[out=45, in=135] (B);
  \draw[->] (B) to[out=-135, in=-45] (A);
  \draw[help lines] (0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,-0.5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

In the next code `outer sep=0pt` is necessary

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=to]
   \node[draw,circle,outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) (A) {A};
   \node[draw,circle,outer sep=0pt] at (1,0) (B) {B};
   \draw (A) to[out=45, in=135] (B);
   \draw[<-] (B.135) -- ++(-0.001,0.0009);
   \draw (A) to[out=-45, in=-135] (B);
   \draw[<-] (A.-45) -- ++(0.001,-0.0009);
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I know that my second example is not perfext (I just wanted to make a point), sorry for that. And yes, I know I could use a different arrow tip, but I *want* to use the `latex` shape because I like it much better than the default one you suggest. If it were *a bad idea* to use `latex` like you say, then why is it in TikZ?

Comment: It's a bad idea for me because the arrow tip `latex` is too long and the arc to short so It's impossible to place the head of the tip on the line and to keep the tail on the line too. The only solution is to reduce the size of the tip.

Answer (score 3):

A crazy(?) idea:

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, decoration={
      markings, mark=at position 1.0 with {\arrow{>}}}
    ]
    \node[draw,circle] at (0,0) (A) {A};
    \node[draw,circle] at (1,0) (B) {B};
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (A) to[out=45,   in=135] (B); 
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (B) to[out=-135, in=-45] (A);
    \draw[help lines] (0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Now the angle of the arrows is wrong, but perhaps this is preferable to the original asymmetric arc.

Also note that the asymmetry or skew is more or less noticeable depending on the kind of arrow tip used. With default arrow tips it looks perfect. With `stealth` arrow tips the problem appears, but less acute than with `latex` arrow tips.

**Update**
If the arrowtip is allowed to overlap a bit the destination node, the result is better IMHO:

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, decoration={
      markings, mark=at position 1 with {\draw[->] (-0.01,0) -- (0.07,0);}}
    ]
    \node[draw,circle] at (0,0) (A) {A};
    \node[draw,circle] at (1,0) (B) {B};
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (A) to[out=45,   in=135] (B); 
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (B) to[out=-135, in=-45] (A);
    \draw[help lines] (0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]