# tikz-3dplot: Drawing an arc with the let syntax in 3d

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

How can I use the `let` syntax to draw an arc when using `tikz-3dplot`?  At the present, the arc is drawn but doesn't look right.

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);
  \node[coordinate] (P) at (3, 4, 5) {};

  \draw[-latex] (O) -- +(4, 0, 0) node[font = \small, pos = 1.1] {\(x\)}
  coordinate (X);

  \draw[dashed, gray] (P) -- +(0, 0, -5) coordinate (P1) -- (O);

  \draw[-latex] let
    \p0 = (O),
    \p1 = (X),
    \p2 = (P1),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {1cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (O) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why doesn’t it look right? If you add `\draw (O) circle [radius=1cm];` you will see that the arrow tip adds a small nudge to the arc but otherwise it looks correct. See for a similar problem (and no solution) [Why are bent arrows with arrow tips not symmetric in TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62422)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel it doesn't look natural.  It looks skewed or bowed.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel it isn't the arrow tip that is the problem.  It is the arc.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you compared your arc with the `circle` path I posted earlie? If I remove `-latex` from the arc they nicely overlap; with the arrow tip the arc does not overlap perfectly with the circle.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I see what you are saying now.  Is there anything that can be done here?

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is. Your arc looks perfectly fine to me. If you'd like to use the `tikz-3dplot` arc, then you might want to have a look at the macros `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords`, `\tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin` and `\tdplotdrawarc`. See this TeXample for more info: http://texample.net/tikz/examples/the-3dplot-package/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can now be solved with the combination of the `arrows.meta` and `bending` libraries of TikZ/pgf v3.0.0. Switch `-latex` to `-Latex` (the comparable `arrows.meta` variant). Loading `bending` automatically sets `/pgf/arrow keys/flex=1`, which is what's needed to make the arrowed path follow the non-arrowed path (red, dashed path in the sample) exactly.

I also had to swap the arguments of `atan2` in your example for use with v3.0.0

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);
  \node[coordinate] (P) at (3, 4, 5) {};

  \draw[-latex] (O) -- +(4, 0, 0) node[font = \small, pos = 1.1] {\(x\)}
  coordinate (X);

  \draw[dashed, gray] (P) -- +(0, 0, -5) coordinate (P1) -- (O);

  \draw[-Latex] let
    \p0 = (O),
    \p1 = (X),
    \p2 = (P1),
    \n1 = {atan2(\y1 - \y0,\x1 - \x0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\y2 - \y0,\x2 - \x0)},
    \n3 = {1cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (O) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2];
  \draw[red,dashed] let
    \p0 = (O),
    \p1 = (X),
    \p2 = (P1),
    \n1 = {atan2(\y1 - \y0,\x1 - \x0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\y2 - \y0,\x2 - \x0)},
    \n3 = {1cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (O) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]